# How Jenkins pipeline detects changes from all mercurial branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, mercurial

How can i make Jenkins pipeline detects changes from all branches.
I'm using mercurial as SCM and i found in pipeline configuration that Jenkins detects only changes from one branch or from the default.

Comment: Have you try create `Multiple Branch Pipeline` job

Comment: It didn't work for me. I used the same config to clone the project and link it with mercurial. I got this message "There are no branches found that contain buildable projects" when i tried to build.